# Factoring difference of products of orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am working through some problems in Golub and van Loan's *Matrix Computations* and have come across the following problem that has me stumped.

The question involves producing an upper bound on $||Q'_1Q'_2...Q'_n-Q_1Q_2...Q_n||_2$ given $||Q'_i-Q_i||_2$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$.  We know that $Q'_i$ and $Q_i$ are Givens rotations, but not necessarily disjoint, so the multiplication here isn't commutative.  I have thought about trying to use some form of the non-commutative matrix binomial theorem, but am hoping that there is an easier solution out there.

Comment: Sorry, is the matrix norm here the 2-norm on the elements, or the eigenvalues?

Comment: The 2-norm on the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the case $n = 2$. Using the invariant of the $2$-norm under rotations, we have

$$ ||Q_1'Q_2' - Q_1Q_2||_2 = ||Q_1'Q_2' - Q_1Q_2' + Q_1Q_2' - Q_1Q_2||_2 = \\
||(Q_1' - Q_1)Q_2' + Q_1(Q_2' - Q_2)||_2 \leq ||(Q_1' - Q_1)Q_2'|| + ||Q_1(Q_2' - Q_2)|| =
\\
||Q_1' - Q_1|| + ||Q_2' - Q_2||.$$

The general case can be handled by induction by writing "$Q_2' = Q_2' \dots Q_n', Q_2 = Q_2 \dots Q_n$".